# BGP Neighbor description OIDs (Juniper+Cisco)

Tags: bgp, snmp

I would like my BGP peer SNMP alarms to contain the neighbor description within the alarm which will contain e.g. transit provider name/CID/etc. Currently my alarms just contain an ambiguous IP address.

I've been searching extensively and I can't find anything.
The only solution I have discovered so far is to enter descriptions manually on our SNMP monitoring suite.

Comment: That would be the way to do it. The real identifying information is the IP address, which is not ambiguous, but is very specific. That should tell you what you need to know, and you can use it as the key for any other information you want.

Comment: I looked into this fairly extensively awhile back and to my knowledge only Arista currently supports a peer description accessible via SNMP.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

So, the longer answer to your question is that you're "not supposed" to do it that way.  You should have all that overhead configuration in your network monitoring system.  Routers are not very good databases.  For example, if you upgrade your transit connection data rate you might change the CID.  Does that mean you need to change the description on the BGP peer?